# Android: Put two elements in the center of relativeLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I add two elements in the view for code. An imageView and a Spinning Wheel. The two elements shown but in the same place. And I desire to put the ImageView above the other element, in the center of screen.

The code that add the views:

```
    RelativeLayout container= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    imgCenter.setLayoutParams(position);
    container.addView(imgCenter); 

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    position2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    position2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,imgCenter.getId());
    spinner.setLayoutParams(position2);
    container.addView(spinner);
```

The xml of relativelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.app.exemple.LoadingActivity"
android:id="@+id/container" >
```

Comment: Do you mean one should be overlayed over the other or that they should be laid out in a vertical line?

Comment: Try to remove this line : position2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

Comment: if you use LinearLayout with gravity "center" as parent layout instead  of RelativeLayout then you dosn't required to gave any rules etc directly add your image and spinner sequentially.

Comment: @TristanBurnside in vertical line.

Comment: @HareshChhelana if I romeve this line, the spinner is shown on top of the screen and I want that is displayed in bottom of the imageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HareshChhelana I found the solution.
I change the xml as follow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.app.exemple.LoadingActivity"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center" >
```

And the code:

```
LinearLayout container= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    container.addView(imgCenter); 
    container.addView(spinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove center in parent in second child

```
RelativeLayout container= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
imgCenter.setLayoutParams(position);
container.addView(imgCenter); 

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
position2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,imgCenter.getId());
spinner.setLayoutParams(position2);
container.addView(spinner);
```